# Fetch object information from specific position in arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to fetch specific information about a card in an array list.

Each object in the arraylist has 2 characteristics:

```
value // such as ace, 10, jack, 4
suit // diamonds, clubs etc
```

I have the arraylist which holds the shuffled deck of cards, which prints out as this (the method is working, this is just to show the objects):

```
as qd ts 4s ad 5d jd 2s 3h ac 2c 5c 9h 4d 6c 9c 8d 7h 3d 7d 8s qs jc ks jh 3s 7s td 6d 9d kc 8h 4c 4h 8c 2h qc 6s qh
// etc etc, arraylist holds 52 objects (the cards)
```

When a card is dealt from the shuffled pack (shuffled array above), it deletes the card from the shuffled array and moves it to the flop array, of which has a size equal to the total amount of objects inside.

**The deal method for context**

```
private void dealCard(){
    //TODO
    int totalLeftOver = 0; // used to count the cards left in the shuffled-but-not-dealt pack
    Card topCard = shuffledPack.get(0);
    //String dealtCard = topCard.getValue() + topCard.getSuit();
    shuffledPack.remove(0);
    theFlop.add(topCard);
    System.out.print("Cards on the flop: ");
    for(Card dealt : theFlop){
        String definitelyDealt = dealt.getValue() + dealt.getSuit() + " ";
        System.out.print(definitelyDealt);
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
    for(Card card : shuffledPack){ // for loop to count how cards haven't been dealt
        totalLeftOver++;
    }
    System.out.println("Total number of cards not dealt: " + totalLeftOver); // show how many cards haven't been dealt to the player
}
```

I'm now trying to fetch the value and suit of a specific card in the flop array list, depending on position. For simplicity let's say I want to get the information for the last dealt card. Here's what I currently have, which detects the size of the flop:

```
private void makeMovePreviousPile(){
    int lastDealtCardPos = theFlop.size(); //allows us to see how many cards have been dealt, are you even trying to challenge us Chris?
    int previouslyDealtCardPos = lastDealtCardPos - 1;

    if(lastDealtCardPos != 0){ // check that the deck has been shuffled
        String lastCardDealt = lastDealtCardPos.getValue() + lastDealtCardPos.getSuit(); // this doesn't work, its where I'm stuck.
    }
    else { // if it hasn't been shuffled we shun the user.
        System.out.println("Are you sure you shuffled the deck before dealing? Stop trying to cheat.");
        System.out.println("Next time we play Monopoly you won't be the banker. \n");
    }
    //System.out.print(totalDealtCards + " "); // should be equal to the amount of cards we've dealt, if not we've got a problem Huston.
    //System.out.print("Total cards on the flop: " + lastDealtCardPos + " "); // checking to see that its working as intended
    //System.out.print("Previous card dealt: " + previouslyDealtCardPos);
}
```

**Now that we know the size of the flop (how many cards have been dealt) and the position of the last card in the array (in this instance lastDealtCardPos), how would we then fetch the information of the card (such as "ah" for the Ace of Hearts) from this position?**

Previously when cycling through the pack and printing out each card as it gets added into the array, I've used these two methods (which work):

```
    public  String getSuit() {
    return suit;
}

    public  String getValue() {
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, assuming that the flop is indeed an ArrayList and not an Array (your question title and body contradict), you can always do

```
theFlop.get(lastDealtCardPos).getSuit();
theFlop.get(lastDealtCardPos).getValue();
```

Although based on your code, you should remember that `size()` isn't 0 indexed. Therefore, you should set `lastDealtCardPos` to `size()-1`